# Custom Page Title Shortcode within another Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-fields

I use this function to obtain the title of post page in the content area:

```
function myshortcode_title( ){
return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

So, I have a plugin that when I use this shortcode below it read the text beetween the shortcode:

```
[responsivevoice voice="UK English Male"] Wonderful World [/responsivevoice]
```

So, what I'm doing and it's my question also is how can I put the "page title shortcode" within responsivevoice shortcode like this?

```
[responsivevoice voice="UK English Male"] [page_title] [/responsivevoice]
```

(It should get the title of the post page, but it doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one of the following options, and add the code snippet after:

```
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

**Option #1:** `[responsivevoice2]`

```
add_shortcode( 'responsivevoice2', 'responsivevoice2' );
function responsivevoice2( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) {
    if ( $content = do_shortcode( $content ) ) {
        return RV_add_bblisten( $atts, $content );
    }
    return '';
}
```

Sample usage:

```
[responsivevoice2 voice="UK English Male"] [page_title] [/responsivevoice2]
```

This Shortcode allows you to use the `[page_title]` or any other Shortcodes in the
text to be spoken.

**Option #2:** `[responsivevoice_page_title]`

This Shortcode will always use the page title (or the title of the current post)
as the text to be spoken. *With this Shortcode, you don't need the `[page_title]`
Shortcode anymore.*

```
add_shortcode( 'responsivevoice_page_title', 'responsivevoice_page_title' );
function responsivevoice_page_title( $atts = array() ) {
    if ( $page_title = get_the_title() ) {
        return RV_add_bblisten( $atts, $page_title );
    }
    return '';
}
```

Sample usage:

```
[responsivevoice_page_title voice="UK English Male" /]
```